# Wait for completion before executing next step

Tags: swift

I have a few processes that need to be completed in order when my TableView loads. I would expect that it would wait until the code completed before  executing the next line of code, but it seems that's not the case. Is there a way to have these wait until completion before executing the next step?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

performTask1()

performTask2()

performTask3()
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It does wait, unless any of those tasks dispatch blocks of code to be executed on the background, are you doing something like that?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do it (by blocking the main thread). But no, you don't want to do that. Just reload / display your table view once the processes have been completed.

Comment: Yeah, i'm doing a parse "FindObjectInBackground". So if it is something in the background it will kick that off, then hand it back to the original function? Each of the processes is dependent on the other. I guess I could kick the next process off at the end of the previous one, but that doesn't seem as clean to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical example to make each of these methods take a `completionHandler` parameter, e.g.:

```
func perform1(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    doSomethingAsynchronously() {
        completionHandler()
    }
}

func perform2(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    doSomethingElseAsynchronously() {
        completionHandler()
    }
}

func perform3(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    doSomethingCompletelyDifferentAsynchronously() {
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Then you can run them like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    perform1 {
        self.perform2 {
            self.perform3 {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I'll work to create the completion handlers.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob . This looks interesting and I've attempted to test it out, but I'm getting the error `"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"` in Xcode 7.3, Swift 2.2. Any suggestions on how to resolve that? Image of error: http://i.imgur.com/CiwJBay.png

Comment: @user4806509 - Your `doSomethingAsynchronously`, `doSomethingElseAsynchronously`, and `doSomethingCompletelyDifferentAsynchronously` methods do not have completion handlers. Give them completion handler closures that they call when the asynchronous task is done (just like you did for `perform1`, `perform2`, and `perform3`). See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/9f00acd8faec99b6da1c9300dddf7fdc.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Rob .